# Create an aggregate column based on other columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'group'      :["A","A","B","B","B"],
        'A1_val'     :[4,5,7,6,5],
        'A1M_val'     :[10,100,100,10,1],
        'AB_val'     :[4,5,7,6,5],
        'ABM_val'     :[10,100,100,10,1],
        'AM_VAL'     : [4,5,7,6,5]
       } 

# Create DataFrame 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df1

    group   A1_val  A1M_val AB_val  ABM_val AM_VAL
0   A       4       10      4       10       4
1   A       5       100     5       100      5
2   B       7       100     7       100      7
3   B       6       10      6       10       6
4   B       5       1       5       1        5
```

Step 1: I want to create columns as below:
A1_agg_val = sum of A1_val + A1M_val (stripping M out of the column and if the name matches then sum it)

Similarly, AB_agg_val = AB_val + ABM_val

Since there is no matching columns for 'AM_VAL', AM_agg_val = AM_val

```
My expected output:

    group   A1_val  A1M_val AB_val  ABM_val AM_VAL  A1_AGG_val  AB_AGG_val  A_AGG_val
0   A       4       10      4       10       4      14          14          4
1   A       5       100     5       100      5      105         105         5
2   B       7       100     7       100      7      107         107         7
3   B       6       10      6       10       6      16          16          6
4   B       5       1       5       1        5      6           6           5
```

Comment: are the columns always in such order as shown?

Comment: Ya, it should basically check if two columns are equal after stripping "M" which is always in the last position.

Comment: if you strip out M how do you take agg value for AM?

Comment: @anky_91 It is actually going to be A_agg_value. Updated the expected output in the question

Comment: okay can you try this: `c = df1.columns.str.lower().str.endswith('_val')` :
`c1 = df1.columns[c].str.split('_').str[0].str.strip('M')` : `df1.assign(**df1.loc[:,c].groupby(c1,axis=1,sort=False).sum().add_suffix('_agg_value'))` in 3 seperate lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use groupby on `axis=1`

```
out = (df1.assign(**df1.loc[:,df1.columns.str.lower().str.endswith('_val')]
       .groupby(lambda x: x[:2],axis=1).sum().add_suffix('_agg_value')))
```

---

```
print(out)

  group  A1_val  A1M_val  AB_val  ABM_val  AM_VAL  A1_agg_value  AB_agg_value  \
0     A       4       10       4       10       4            14            14   
1     A       5      100       5      100       5           105           105   
2     B       7      100       7      100       7           107           107   
3     B       6       10       6       10       6            16            16   
4     B       5        1       5        1       5             6             6   

   AM_agg_value  
0             4  
1             5  
2             7  
3             6  
4             5
```

Comment: The calculation should only happen on columns with "_val" suffix

Comment: Super elegant @anky_91, made me discover `assign`.